# Mirror desktop screen to phone screen using android studio and or adb

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, adb

How do I mirror my desktop screen to my android phone screen via a USB cable. I'm developing in Android Studio and want the desktop screen to be displayed live in the android app.

Apart from the mobile app there is a desktop app in C++ that can be used for this. It is currently being used for sending and receiving adb commands.

**Device information:**
-Android Version 12, API 31

-Windows 11 (Pro)